# Testing after migrating LAMP install on CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, migration, lamp

I copied the `/var/www/html/site` directory to a new server and all of the `/etc/httpd` conf files, installed the necessary Perl modules, php, and ran `cat mysqldumpfile.sql |mysql db_name` to import the last full db dump from the old server. I edited the links to the old IP and pointed it to the new, the old server is still running.  I then connected to it at newIP/sitedir  and it seemed to work.  Clicking links seemed to all follow within the same url, newIP/site but I want to be sure that there are no references to the old IP or server name in the MySQL database.  How can I be sure, without taking down the old site, that I have a successful migration and that nothing is pointing to the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear you. I had gone through similar experience before. Here are some of the things you can do to confirm that you have successfully migrated the site with no references to the old IP or hostname -

`1.` Recursively search `grep -r` or `grep -R` the `/var/www/html/site`, `/etc/httpd` , mysqldump file for any references to the old IP or hostnames. Most database sites tend to places the mysql host reference in `.conf`, `.inc` or `.php` files, so pay attention to those files.

`2.` Shutdown the mysql service in the old server, and check all links to your site. If there is any reference to the old IP, you will encounter page timed out issues.

`3.` Run `tcpdump` or any other packet analyzer on the old and new servers, if any of the servers is capturing traffic destined to the old IP. Test this, while trying to click all the links on your new site.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` the MySQL dump file for the old IP address and name? Quick and easy.

Comment: Not a bad idea!  So I found some instances of the old hostname in the sql dump.  After the migration, I am planning on creating a cname for the new host that points to the old host name (so the new host will receive any requests to the old server).  Should that suffice?

Comment: A lot of the results I see from grep don't show the server name, they just show \0\0\0\0\0\0\0 for pages and pages, is that binary data or some thing that's encrypted?